# Docker container automation on the cloud

Tags: docker, mesos, kubernetes

I am new to docker and container management.

I read about it, did some test and thought I was up and ready for it when I hit my first roadblock.

I am trying to setup a zookeeper cluster. An ideal cluster size is 2 and I want to containerize zookeeper. Now to automate this task is a problem.

I have been scouring the net for the past several hours on how to do it, and am blocked.
I see that we can use Mesos-Kubernetes, Mesos-Marathos, Aurora, Mesos-Chronos, combinations involving CoreOS, etc.

How do I decide what do I go with? Which one is the best to bring up a scalable infrastructure that heavily depends on containers?

I know its more of a design/architecture question, than a programming one. Is there any other site I can post this to, if not here?

Answer (score 2):

We don't have an independent example for running Zookeeper on Kubernetes, but I noticed that [the example for running Storm on Kubernetes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/storm) includes startup Zookeeper as one of the steps. It looks like the [JSON config that example uses](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/storm/zookeeper.json) pulls a Zookeeper container that the author of the example created. I don't know if there is an "official" Zookeeper container distribution but there are quite a few hits for "Zookeeper" in the public [DockerHub registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com).

Hopefully these pointers are enough to get you started. If you have more questions, please feel free to ask on our mailing list (google-containers@googlegroups.com; join by going to groups.google.com and joining the google-containers list).

I am not familiar with how to run Zookeeper on Mesos, but I know it is definitely possible.

Comment: It's definitely possible and after 3 months have the setup up and running. Thanks! :)